# Ошибка при подключении к ssh серверу на Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, terminal, gnome

У меня Ubuntu, когда я в терминале хочу подключиться к ssh
мне пишет:

```
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Host key verification failed.
```

И так при подключении к любому ssh серверу, что делать?

Comment: LightGryph0n, если помогло, отметь как ответ... имейте уважение к тем, кто вам помогает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо переустановить пакет `ssh-askpass-gnome` через команду `sudo aptitude -y reinstall ssh-askpass-gnome`.